# How do I wire multiple light fixtures on their own switch on a Modular wall?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, vanity

I have a wall that will be used to display vanities. This wall needs to be able to move around and hold 3 light fixtures. Those three fixtures each need their own switch. My thought was to install gang boxes as if it were a traditional wall so that it can be sheetrocked. I need these three fixtures and 3 switches to connect to a plug that can be plugged into a standard outlet. Ive believe I have the wiring figured out but want to be sure before I present the idea/drawing to my boss. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What is the question?